# Calculate the area of the region

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification, area

How to solve the below problem?

> Calculate the area of the region enclosed by the lines $y = x$, $x = 0$ and $y + x = 2$, and is above the plane $xy$.

Here is my solution:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQG8j.jpg]

Please tell my if i solve it correct.

Comment: please show what you have tried or else you will get downvotes

Comment: @HariRamakrishnanSudhakar Please wait to write it clear and i post my solution

Comment: Did you draw the graph?

Comment: Are you searching for a more intuitive graphical solution, or a rigorous solution using integration?

Comment: @SarGe Yes. I Post my solution also. You can check it. Tell me please if it is correct.

Comment: @RCucullatus both.  I post my solution also. You can check it. Tell me please if it is correct.

Comment: @HariRamakrishnanSudhakar I post my solution. Please remove the downvotes.

Comment: by the way  i did not downvote and neither can i remove the downvotes put by others.

Comment: @Andreas, it is correct. Also, the downvotes might be due to poor formatting. Typeset mathematical terms using MathJax rather than posting image. [Here's the tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @HariRamakrishnanSudhakar okay!

Comment: @SarGe Thank you a lot my friend!

Comment: One way in which you could know that it is indeed correct is looking at the graph and, as the area you are looking for is a triangle, compute directly its value.

Comment: @Patricio Yes, I saw it after. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

It is correct. You can check it by just subtracting the areas: $\int_{0}^{1}(2-x)dx-\int_{0}^{1}(x)dx=(2x-\frac{x^2}{2})\vert _{0}^{1}-\frac{x^2}{2}\vert_{0}^{1}=2-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}=1$